# How to pass a final groupBy() to a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Please help me understand KafkaStreams. there is a code that does a normal groupBy():

```java
public static void createGroupByStream(final StreamsBuilder builder) {   
    KStream<String, Person> stream = builder.stream("kafka-stream-input", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.PersonSerde()));  
      stream  
            .groupByKey()  
            .reduce((item, second) -> {  
                item.setCount(item.getCount() + second.getCount());  
                return item;  
            } )  
            .toStream()  
            .to("kafka-stream-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.PersonSerde()));  
}
```

class Person:

```java
public class Person extends GroupingEntity {  
    private String name;  
    private int count;
    }
```

class CustomSerdes:

```java
public final class CustomSerdes {  
 
    public static Serde<Person> PersonSerde() {  
        JsonSerializer<Person> serializer = new JsonSerializer<>();  
        JsonDeserializer<Person> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Person.class);  
        return Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer);  
    }
```

At the moment, the data is updated in a stream, i.e. the "kafka-stream-output" topic stores the entire history of updating the count field for each Person.
I want the output topic (in the example it is "kafka-stream-output") to show information only when all messages from the "kafka-stream-input" topic have been processed. Those. there was only the final groupBy. Can you suggest how to do this?

The data is transferred from a csv file, where each line is one message. There may be a large number (several millions)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3xhb.png)
Those. in theory, I can initially count the number of rows (*count*) and wait until the *count *messages in the topic are processed. But how to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the previous answer, Kafka Streams doesn't have a concept of "done" since event streams are considered infinite. One thing to consider is using [windowing](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html#windowedBy-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windows-) with [suppression](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html#suppress-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed-) and only emitting a result when [the window closes](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.4.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Suppressed.html#untilWindowCloses-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed.StrictBufferConfig-).

Answer (score 0):

Kafka isn't doing batch processing, therefore will not wait until all data is processed.

If that's what you want, you'll need at least a KTable, rather than output to a Stream, then use Interactive Queries to fetch data from that table... However, if you lookup data while consumption is happening, you'll not see the most recent count

If you simple want to aggregate a CSV file, then other tools like DuckDB, Pandas, Spark, etc would be better. On a related note, CSV data wouldn't be parsable from a JSON serde